# How to make a loading screen GUI wait for the game to loaded first before deleting itself? in Roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I was developeding a game using Roblox studio (Roblox Game engine) I was just making a simple loading screen that stay until the game is fully loaded but I don't know how to make the loading screen actually stay on the user ScreenGUI until the game fully loaded.

I want to make a simple loading screen on Roblox studio that deleted itself after the game fully loaded.
But I don't know how to make the loading screen to wait for the game to fully loaded first before deleting itself.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [ReplicatedFirst:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ReplicatedFirst#RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen), and the [game.Loaded](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/DataModel#Loaded) signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a script inside the GUI, the GUI elements should be in a GUI element (other than ScreenGUI) to make it easier, and the script should be in that element. Here is what the script would look like:

```
frame = script.Parent
game.Loaded:Connect(function() 
    frame.Visible = false
end)
```

This script checks if the game is loaded, and when it is, it hides the parent. As stated before, the parent should be the frame holding all the content, or any other GUI element, I would recommend Frame, as it is only a bold color and will not have any effect unless applied in the Frame or through a script.

Comment: Jeez, I forgot I had this post, I would be able to do this easily now.